# How to guess the value of $j$ at the end of the loop?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, integers

```
for ( i = n , j = 0 ; i > 0 ; i = i / 2 , j = j + i ) ;
```

All variables are integers.(i.e. if decimal values occur, consider their floor value)

Let $\text{val}(j)$ denote the value of $j$, after the termination of the loop. Which of the following is true?

(A)$\quad \text{val(j)} = \Theta(\log(n)) $ 
(B)$\quad \text{val(j)} = \Theta(\sqrt n) $ 
(C)$\quad \text{val(j)} = \Theta(n) $ 
(D)$\quad \text{val(j)} = \Theta(\log\log n) $

Please explain, is there any easy way to guess the value of $j$?

Comment: How about running the program.

Comment: @DaveClarke Running the program just gives the result of a particular input. But a more general proof/formula is needed.

Comment: Run it on multiple inputs.

Comment: Sounds like homework/test, is that true ?

Comment: @Bartek lol no! just trying to understand.. But I have no clue where to start..

Comment: You should try your best before asking such questions. Try to make a table of i,j value. i starts from n and j starts from 0. In every iteration, write down the value of i and j. for example i=n/2 and j=1. Write i as a function of the previous value. That is, in the next iteration (n/2)/2 ... etc .. until i is less than 0. Does the value of i look anything similar to you ?

Comment: @AJed as a matter of fact, I did. ... 
For i=n, j=n ... 
For i=n/2 , j= n + n/2 ... 
For i=n/4 , j= n + n/2 + n/4 ...

Comment: Ok- this is correct, then write $j$ as a sum ($\sum$) equation. Use some known formulas. (Hint: you have $(1/2)^i$ repeating itself there).(Hint: look at geometric series - there is a well-known cheat sheet for Theoretical CS. Find it in the internet).

Comment: There is a silly trick I have just found out. This loop never ends.

Comment: @AJed did you consider the variables as integers or decimal numbers? FYI they are integers. I've added this info to the question.

Comment: @AJed Actually for any implementation of the variable $i$ which uses a finite number of bits, the loop will terminate. However, even if the loop didn't terminate, you could still answer the question. On every iteration of the loop, $j = \Theta(n)$, and this is not true for any other of the choices.

Comment: Guys, I finally solved it.. check my answer below.. let me know if there are any discrepancies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break the loop as

```
j = 0; 
for ( i = n ; i > 0 ; i = i/2 ) 
     j = j + i ;
```

Since the input size decreases by half, the total number of iterations would be $\log(n)+1 $

As $i$ becomes $n, n/2 , n/4 \ldots$ up to $\log(n)+1 $ terms, the corresponding $j$ value gets added. 
So, $val(j) = n+n/2+n/4+n/8+\ldots n/2^{\log(n)} $

$val(j) = n ( 1 + 1/2+1/4+1/8+\ldots 1/2^{\log(n)})$

Performing sum of geometric series,

$S_n = \frac{1 - (1/2)^{\log(n)}}{1 - (1/2)} $

We know that $a^{\log(b)} = b^{\log(a)}$
Thus $2^{\log(n)} = n^{\log(2)} = n$

$S_n = \frac{2(n-1)}{n}$

$val(j) = n\frac{2(n-1)}{n}$

$val(j) = 2(n-1)$

Thus, $val(j) = \Theta(n)$

Comment: so what you do is taking someone else answer and cite it to yourself ? :)

Comment: oh sorry AJed! I didn't see your answer after you made your last edit. I was actually having problems in finding the sum of geometric series. And furthermore, though asymptotically your answer is correct, it has minor glitches. Since the answer is asked in tight bound, even a minor error can cause major deviation in the result. But thank you so much for your answer.. Now I can confirm that I'm in the right direction and that my answer is correct

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244817/ You should give credit to the people that helped you to come up with "your" answer.

Comment: @A.Schulz lol..actually that question was also asked by me :) Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 3):

If you unfold the loop you get:

$$\text{val}( j)=n+n/2+n/4+ n/8 \ldots$$

In total you have $\log n$ terms.
See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244817/), how to evaluate the sum.

Comment: It may depend on the particular programming language, but generally, since `i=i/2` is written first, the sum should probably begin with $n/2$ instead of $n$

Comment: @Paresh it doesnt really matter as we are looking for an upper bound.

Comment: @AJed Aah ... missed that part.

Comment: @A.Schulz are you sure about log n terms. isn't it log(n)+1 terms

Comment: @VISHNUVIVEK: Actually it is $\lfloor\log  n \rfloor +1$, but these subtleties do not make a difference regarding your question.

Comment: @AJed we're actually looking for a lower and upper bound $\Theta()$, but it still doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

In theoretical processor, this loops never ends. Dividing $i$ by 2 repetitively will always lead to i > 0. [This has been changed in the Q. description]
Therefore:

$ j = n + n/2 + n/4 ... $

$ j = \sum _{i = 0} ^{\inf} n (1/2)^{i}= n \sum _{i = 0} ^{\inf} (1/2)^{i}$

Given that $\sum _{i = 1} ^{\inf} c^i = c / (1 - c) $ then the solution of this equation is $j = 2 n$

In your integer program, follow the link posted by @A.Schulz. -- If you compute the geometric series provided, it will end up to the same approximate result. so you guess your answer.

More details:

given that $\sum _{i = 0} ^{\log n} (1/2)^i = \frac{(1/2)^{\log n + 1} - 1}{(1/2) - 1} = 2( 1 - 1/2n) = 2 - 1/n $

Then, the final result is $n (2 - 1/n) = 2n - 1$ . Therefore, it is C.

Comment: those are not float variables.. you've to perform integer division.. in programming, if you don't mention the data-type of a variable, it'll be taken as integer by default

Comment: check the edit !

Comment: Actually for any implementation of the variable $i$ which uses a finite number of bits, the loop will terminate. However, even if the loop didn't terminate, you could still answer the question. On every iteration of the loop, $j = \Theta(n)$, and this is not true for any other of the choices.